# Setting variable from select query

Tags: php, mysql, select, session-variables

Not the most experience PHP-esque person out there, however due to need and requirement, I've slowly started to construct a "login" system for an internal/external project.

Users are logged in, and then able to search for scanned TIF images based on three-data fields, however; as there are multiple customers in the tables, I want to restrict queries to the logged in users "Customer Code"

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$md5'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {

$_SESSION['username'] = strtoupper($username);
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['customercode'] = $result['customercode'];

header('location:home.php');

} else {

echo '<h1>Wrong Username or Password</h1>';
}
```

Simple login mechanism which works as intended and applies appropriate `$_SESSION['username'] = strtoupper($username);` however cannot seem to get the row `customercode` from the `$result` to show correctly?

Are SELECT queries from a mysql database able to be used as Session Variables?

Thanks -

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: Brave soul, not protecting agains injection attacks, _and_ using deprecated functions...

Comment: * not all the code is included, injection attacks are covered, and as a base mysql_* is used until everything is changed to mysqli_* it's development at this stage - Thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the mysql_fetch_* to get the customeCode:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result); //add this line

$_SESSION['username'] = strtoupper($username);
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['customercode'] = $data['customercode'];

}
```

> Note: As on most of the question all are recommend, I also recommend
>   to you to use the mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_*